# Why is memcpy not functioning properly?

Tags: c++, memcpy

I have a class for an RDT Header that holds information for an implementation of several reliable data transfer protocols. I need to attach that information (a total of 12 bytes) to my send buffer to transfer it over the socket. I am trying to use memcpy to do this but for some reason it just leaves junk inside the buffer. Below is the line of code that isnt working. (RDT_HDR_SIZE is defined as 12).

Definition of variables that are passed to this function.

```
char payload[] = "sample code sample code";
int payload_size = sizeof(payload) ; 
int pktsize = payload_size + sizeof( RdtHeader )+1 ; // 1 byte for NULL-terminated
char * send_buf = new char[pktsize];
```

The function with memcpy that is having issues.

```
unsigned int Sender::CreateSegment( char * buf, 
         char payload[], int payload_size, unsigned long seqnum ) {
     RdtHeader * header = (RdtHeader *) buf; 
     // set rdt fields:
     header->ack = 0; 
     header->fin = 0; 
     header->ok = 0; 
     header->seq = seqnum; 
     header->win = 0;
     header->syn = 0;
     memcpy( buf+RDT_HDR_SIZE, payload, payload_size );

     return (payload_size + RDT_HDR_SIZE + 1);
}
```

If i take out RDT_HDR_SIZE, the payload is assigned properly to buf, however it wipes out all my header fields. Any idea how to get this to work?

Thanks,

Eric R.

EDIT:

Here is the code for my RdtHeader class -- perhaps it will be of use.

```
class RdtHeader{    // 12-byte header 
public: 
//1-byte flags field
    u_char protocol:2;      // 2 bits: protocol type = 0 for RDT3, 1 for GBN, and 2 for STCP    
    u_char syn:1;           // 1 bit: SYN = 1 for connection setup  
    u_char fin:1;           // 1 bit: FIN = 1 for termination
    u_char ok:1;            // 1 bit: OK = 1 receiver agrees, SYN_OK or FIN_OK
    u_char reserved:3;      // 3 bits: unused

    u_char unused;          // 1-byte unused filed; 

    u_short win;            // 2-byte receiver window size (the number of packets)
    u_long seq;             // 4-byte sequence number
    u_long ack;             // 4-byte ack number
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using sizeof(RdtHeader) rather than hard coding the buffer size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be too obvious, but exactly how are you inspecting the buffer?

Have you tried

```
printf( "%s\n", send_buf + sizeof(RdtHeader) );
```

?

If you instead are doing ...

```
printf( "%s\n", send_buf );
```

... then you should *expect* to see just garbage (with correct operation) since the `win` field acts as zero-terminator for the "string" that that latter call is printing.

Cheers & hth.,

– Alf

Comment: /facepalm --- Ok, so basically the moral of the story is that I technically gave it a null terminator when assigning values to my RdtHeader. Thank you for pointing this out. I just couldn't make sense of why my memcpy wasnt working when I felt it should have been fine. 

Occams Razor...Wasn't the copy, but how I was seeing what was copied.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark said, look at sizeof(RdtHeader). There might be some padding inside the struct (especially since there is a long int there) that throws the calculations off.

But other than that, I don't see an obvious problem here. I would try to add some print-outs, if you're running it in an environment where that is feasible, or try a debugger. Possibly the real problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I tried memcpy(buf+sizeof(RdtHeader), payload, payload_size) and still doesn't copy. It just leaves junk in the buffer. I placed a printf right after the memcpy and does not have the payload in it. I edited the original post and added my class definition for RdtHeader

Answer (score 0):

```
memcpy(header + 1, payload, payload_size + 1);
return sizeof(*header) + payload_size + 1;
```

- You're mysteriously returning an
  extra `1`, suggesting the payload is
  a null-terminated string. You might
  want to copy that terminator, so it's
  included in the last `memcpy`
  parameter.
- By using the `header` pointer to calculate the memcpy destination, you'll never have to cast if types change, in particular if you change the type of `buf`. You can rely on the fact that C++ allows `X *` to degrade to `void *` to avoid ugly casting.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by this. Using the code you provided, there is no change in the output. My buffer still just holds junk. If I remove the addition on the pointers in memcpy (whether using the header, or buf), payload is copied fine, but I lose all my header information.